# Could not import 'rest_framework.authentication.OAuth2Authentication'

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0

I am new to Django. I am trying to set up OAuth in django and I got this error.

[image]

My setting.py is something like this. Is there anything that I need to install?

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {    
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES':
        ('rest_framework.authentication.OAuth2Authentication',
         'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication'),

    'DEFAULT_MODEL_SERIALIZER_CLASS':
        'rest_framework.serializers.ModelSerializer',

    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES':
    ('rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser',)
}

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'rest_framework',
    'provider',
    'provider.oauth2',
    'todo'
)
```

Comment: Have you added `'rest_framework'` to `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Yes. I have put that one.

Comment: Which django version do you use?

Comment: I use 1.7 but I try with 1.8 also.but not okay

Answer (score 0):

Your settings must look like this:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {    
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES':
        ('oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
         'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication'),

    'DEFAULT_MODEL_SERIALIZER_CLASS':
        'rest_framework.serializers.ModelSerializer',

    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES':
    ('rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser',)
}

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'rest_framework',
    'oauth2_provider',
    'todo'
)
```